# Use colorbox inside a lstlisting without losing other formatting?

Tags: formatting, listings

I have a lstlisting defined as follow

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,frame=single]
Offset(P)  Local Address             Remote Address            Pid
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ---
0x01e6a9f0 192.168.0.176:1176        212.150.164.203:80        888
0x01ec57c0 192.168.0.176:1189        192.168.0.1:9393          1244
0x01ed4270 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30379         1244
0x01eef808 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30380         4
0x01ffa7f8 0.0.0.0:0                 80.206.204.129:0          0
0x02041108 127.0.0.1:1168            127.0.0.1:1169            888
0x0225a448 192.168.0.176:1172        66.249.91.104:80          888
0x0226ac58 127.0.0.1:1169            127.0.0.1:1168            888
0x0227ac58 192.168.0.176:1171        66.249.90.104:80          888
0x02308890 192.168.0.176:1178        212.150.164.203:80        1752
0x02323008 192.168.0.176:1184        193.104.22.71:80          880
0x02410440 192.168.0.176:1185        193.104.22.71:80          880
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want to highlight certain lines so I have tried doing it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,escapeinside={<@}{@>},frame=single]
Offset(P)  Local Address             Remote Address            Pid
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ---
<@\colorbox{yellow}{0x01e6a9f0 192.168.0.176:1176        212.150.164.203:80        888}@>
0x01ec57c0 192.168.0.176:1189        192.168.0.1:9393          1244
0x01ed4270 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30379         1244
0x01eef808 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30380         4
0x01ffa7f8 0.0.0.0:0                 80.206.204.129:0          0
0x02041108 127.0.0.1:1168            127.0.0.1:1169            888
0x0225a448 192.168.0.176:1172        66.249.91.104:80          888
0x0226ac58 127.0.0.1:1169            127.0.0.1:1168            888
0x0227ac58 192.168.0.176:1171        66.249.90.104:80          888
0x02308890 192.168.0.176:1178        212.150.164.203:80        1752
0x02323008 192.168.0.176:1184        193.104.22.71:80          880
0x02410440 192.168.0.176:1185        193.104.22.71:80          880
\end{lstlisting}
```

But the highlighted line loses the previous formatting. I'm not sure how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat a bit by using three listings, and setting a background color for the middle one. Some adjustments are needed for the vertical margin using `aboveskip` and `belowskip`. The frame can be drawn separately with the `framed` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\scriptsize
\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=0pt]
Offset(P)  Local Address             Remote Address            Pid
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ---
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt]
0x01e6a9f0 192.168.0.176:1176        212.150.164.203:80        888+
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=0pt]
0x01ec57c0 192.168.0.176:1189        192.168.0.1:9393          1244
0x01ed4270 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30379         1244
0x01eef808 192.168.0.176:2869        192.168.0.1:30380         4
0x01ffa7f8 0.0.0.0:0                 80.206.204.129:0          0
0x02041108 127.0.0.1:1168            127.0.0.1:1169            888
0x0225a448 192.168.0.176:1172        66.249.91.104:80          888
0x0226ac58 127.0.0.1:1169            127.0.0.1:1168            888
0x0227ac58 192.168.0.176:1171        66.249.90.104:80          888
0x02308890 192.168.0.176:1178        212.150.164.203:80        1752
0x02323008 192.168.0.176:1184        193.104.22.71:80          880
0x02410440 192.168.0.176:1185        193.104.22.71:80          880
\end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This will work perfectly. Thanks